# Which version of python extension support python3.6 in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.6

I'm shifting from pycharm to vscode for python development and want to check if most of functionality from pycharm such as debugging, gitlab integration, etc... Are possible in VScode.

I've learned that you could install python extension so I did install python v.2022.20.1 extension. However this debugging functionality does not work when I use python 3.6(it says in python extension that it supports python 3.7 and above). I want to find a version that support python 3.6, how can I find it?

I can click drop down beside uninstall block and install another version however there are lots of versions and it is cumbersome to click each one to check...

Comment: Certainly outside the scope of the question as posed, but why is it you’re looking to continue using Python 3.6 when its last security update was over a year ago?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `2022.08.*` or previous versions, later versions no longer support `python3.6`.

[image]